# Using PHP variable inside function

Tags: php

I use the following code to get the full filename of a package using only the name of the app:

```
<?php   

// define which app
$app = "appname"; 

// Search the directory for possible matches
foreach (glob("../../debs/com.dev.".$app."*") as $filename) {

preg_match('/\\d\\.\\d-\\d_.*\\.deb/', $filename, $matches);
    $debname = "com.dev.".$app."_{$matches[0]}\n"; }
    echo $debname;
?>
```

The filename of the package ($debname) is then shown correctly in the `echo` as: `com.dev.appname_1.0-1_iphoneos-arm.deb`

So i'm then trying to use this $debname variable to get the size of the file:

```
<?php function format_size($size) {
      $sizes = array(" Bytes", " KB", " MB", " GB", " TB", " PB", " EB", " ZB", " YB");
      if ($size == 0) { return('n/a'); } else {
      return (round($size/pow(1024, ($i = floor(log($size, 1024)))), 2) . $sizes[$i]); }
}
    echo format_size(filesize("../../debs/".$debname));
?>
```

For some weird reason the code is not showing the size and it shows n/a

If i set the debname variable manually to `$debname = "com.dev.appname_1.0-1_iphoneos-arm.deb"` it works fine and i get the file size..

I just can't figure out what's the problem

I tried using SESSION..

```
session_start();
$SESSION['debname'] = $debname;
...
...
echo format_size(filesize("../../debs/".$SESSION['debname']));
```

But same issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
$debname = "com.dev.".$app."_{$matches[0]}\n";
                                          ^^ new-line character
```

Note that you are adding a new-line to the end of your string. You should remove that and confirm the correct name with a `var_dump($debname);` if necessary to make sure there are no white-spaces in between or at the end:

```
$debname = "com.dev.".$app."_{$matches[0]}";
```

Comment: oh damn! i am officially blind, how i couldn't see the `\n` :/
Thanks mate!